# Unable to execute TekRadius CLI from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, command-line-interface, radius

TekRadius is a Radius server that I want to access through my ASP.NET application. I first tried to execute TekRadius CLI directly using C#. But it didn't worked. Now I am trying to execute it through CMD by calling it in C# code like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C \"c:\Program Files (x86)\TekRADIUS LT\trclilt.exe\" -u " + username + " " + password;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
string line = "";
while (!process.StandardError.EndOfStream)
{
    line = line + "\n" + process.StandardError.ReadLine();
}
File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\error.txt"), line);
```

TekRadius is working fine when executed directly through CLI or GUI or through Visual Studio's Internal Server. But on main server my custom error log `error.txt` is showing this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\System.Data.SQLite.dll' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at ????????????????????????????????????????.????????????????????????????????????????(String , String )
   at ????????????????????????????????????????.????????????????????????????????????????()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at ????????????????????????????????????????(String[] )
```

TekRadius CLI uses SQLLite for storing its username and password. And I know its the TekRadius that is unable to access 'C:\Windows\TEMP\System.Data.SQLite.dll', not my application because I am using SQL Server and my above C# code is not making any attempts to access database. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am also unable to set new permissions on Windows folder. Please tell me what can I do to give access to this location to TekRadius CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 12 hours I was able to solve it by myself. Solution was to give full control to `ISS_IUSRS` for `System.Data.SQLite.dll` in `C:\Windows\Temp` folder. Also, do the same for `c:\Program Files (x86)\TekRADIUS LT\trclilt.exe`.